# view - looking for an event like on(View)Destroyed

Tags: android, view, ondestroy

Is there any way to listen to such an event?

I have a custom EditText, which shows a FragmentDialog if it is clicked to pick a time, distance or a number, depending on the EditText setup...

Now I'm using event bus based FragmentDialogs in my whole application and I want to register the view on the bus and unregister it, if the view is destroyed...

But I don't know, where I could unregister it...

Comment: onDetachFromWindow could be one. see https://plus.google.com/u/0/+ArpitMathur/posts/cT1EuBbxEgN

Comment: that's what I'm testing right now... but I'm not sure if this always works, I already read something about this function not always being called...

Answer (score 2):

A `View` is added over your activity/fragment/Dialog etc. Therefore it doesn't have its own `onDestroy` alike event. So instead, use activity's/fragment's `onDestroy` method to identify when the `View` is not valid anymore.

Comment: I know that... What I want is a independent view, which handles it's dialogs itself (what I already have), but I don't want to make an WeakReference bus to handle my views... therefore, and only for this bus system, I need to unregsiter the view before it get's destroyed... onDetachFromWindow seems to work so far...

Comment: btw, I'm including them sometimes in xml as well, and I don't know, if the view is part of an activity or fragment... of course, I could iterate over all views in the `onDestroy` of the fragment/activity as well, but that seems to be just a workaround...